# Javascript canvas green ellipse left and red right side

Tags: javascript, random, p5.js, ellipse

I want to make green ellipses on left side and red ellipses on right side. I use random function to fill the canvas. I use if statements for my purpose. Maybe switch case would be better for this task? 
This syntax only generate pink dots, whats wrong?

```js
var spotPos = {
  x:300,
  y:200
}

var spotCol = {
  r:0,
  g:0,
  b:0
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600,400);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  spotPos.x = random(0,width);
  spotPos.y = random(0,height);
  //spotCol.r = random(60,255);
  noStroke()
  fill(spotCol.r, spotCol.g, spotCol.b)
  ellipse(spotPos.x, spotPos.y, 25, 25);
  if(spotPos.x < 300) {
    spotCol.b = 255;
  } else if(spotPos.x > 300) {
    spotCol.r = 255;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: post complete example with code snippet.

Comment: Please specify which libraries you are using. Is it p5.js?

Comment: Previous commenters make valid points. I've already suggested an edit to the question to reflect that you are using `p5.js` and convert the code into a snippet. For future questions keep those comments in mind and maybe also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

There were a few things preventing you from achieving your desired result.

First you **drew the ellipse and then afterwards selected a color**. That meant that in the next round of the `draw` loop, the ellipse will be drawn somewhere else but the color will still be based on the previous position.

The second problem was the assignment of RGB values:

```
  if(spotPos.x < 300) {
    spotCol.b = 255;
  } else if(spotPos.x > 300) {
    spotCol.r = 255;
  }
```

You only ever assigned *blue* and *red* a value of 255 and **never changed it backed**. So after a few iterations you have `fill(255, 0, 255)` e.g. full red, no green, full blue which resulted in the pink color you were seeing.

Think of `draw` as a set of instructions that you repeat over and over again. You need to consider the **order of your instructions** and in **what state you end/start** each iteration of your loop. If you change some global variables how will they affect your program the next time `draw` is run?

I've included a working example below but feel free to experiment with your own ideas and solutions.

```js
const spotPos = {
  x: 300,
  y: 200
}

const spotCol = {
  r: 0,
  g: 0,
  b: 0
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  spotPos.x = random(0, width);
  spotPos.y = random(0, height);

  if (spotPos.x < 300) {
    spotCol.r = 0;
    spotCol.g = 255;
  } else if (spotPos.x > 300) {
    spotCol.r = 255;
    spotCol.g = 0;
  }
  
  noStroke();
  fill(spotCol.r, spotCol.g, spotCol.b)
  ellipse(spotPos.x, spotPos.y, 25, 25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you draw the circle first before coloring it, it won't detect the new color.